# Can Cisco vpn client .pcf file from a PC be used on a Mac?

Tags: macos, cisco-vpn-client

i recently switched from a PC to a Mac. I want to know if my previous Cisco VPN client .pcf file installed on my PC can be used on my Mac OS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the file will work on any OS as-is, but if you have Snow Leopard or later, you don't need the client software at all.  OSX has a VPN client built in that will work (you'll still need the settings from the .pcf file ... host, group name, group password, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't always true if the port or Tunneling Mode are something other than the defaults in the PCF file.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the profile pcf file from a Windows to a Linux system, see no reason why it wouldn't work on a Mac.